# Can I bookmark a question on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, questions, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

I don't know if a bookmarking feature is available already. Sometimes I come across a question (not necessarily my own), and would like to bookmark it/put it on a watch list so I can follow its progress.

I could use my browser's bookmark feature, but it'd be a lot tidier if Stack Overflow could handle it. That way, the list would be available on any computer I use.

Comment: @Robo questions about SO itself belong on http://meta.stackoverflow.com. And yes, the "Star icon" to the left of a question will add it to the "Favorites" tab on your user page.

Comment: I've suggested to rename favorites to bookmarks to avoid confusion at http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97315/163139

Answer (score 7):

Belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com, but yes, you can click the star under the vote total.

Comment: Damn, beaten! :P

Comment: Seems like a bit of a hack...

Answer (score 1):

Click the Favourite (star) icon under the voting control.