# Can one mark individual threads as "favourite"?

Tags: support, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is there any way to favorite / bookmark an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1569/is-there-any-way-to-favorite-bookmark-an-answer)
>   [Can I bookmark a question on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23670/can-i-bookmark-a-question-on-stack-overflow)

Hello,

Some threads match my tags and that's okay.

However, there are threads that I would like to have as "favourites" regardless of whether they match any of my tags.

If I could add a unique tag to such threads, that would not be a good idea because it creates a global tag clutter.

Is there a better alternative?

Comment: see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1569/is-there-any-way-to-favorite-bookmark-an-answer although I see now that one is about answers... there must be one about questions as well.

Comment: there it is: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23670/can-i-bookmark-a-question-on-stack-overflow this one is an exact dupe

Comment: There is another alternative: *use your browser's bookmark system*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Click the star beneath the vote-counter. This marks that particular thread as a "favorite." Once a question is marked as "favorite," it will show up in your "Favorites" tab on your user profile.

[alt text http://sstatic.net/mso/img/vote-favorite-off.png](http://sstatic.net/mso/img/vote-favorite-off.png)

Comment: It seems that some wish to down vote Jonathan.

This seems unkind imo.  Jonathan, I appreciate your answer.

Comment: @gerryLowry: You'll find this type of behavior a lot around here. Best advice is to toughen up and don't take it personally :)

Answer (score 7):

You should just click the star under the voting controls.

[alt text http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/6719/sofavoritestar.png](http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/6719/sofavoritestar.png)

---

[alt text http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/6719/sofavoritestar.png](http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/6719/sofavoritestar.png)