# How about a "My History" feature

Tags: feature-request, questions, user-interface

Is it possible to show the history of the questions I have visited. This will come in handy if I saw a question, but didnt fav it, and want to visit it again. Sometimes it is difficult to find it using site search or even google search. So such a feature would be very welcome. On a related note we can have a "learning trail" of the user, tracing which questions they opened from a listing and how did they navigate between the questions

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I bookmark a question on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23670/can-i-bookmark-a-question-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: This isn't a full solution, but you can see a partial history at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/132753/midhat?tab=activity. That tab of your profile will list questions that you've performed non-trivial actions at.

Comment: If you've commented or answered said question, it will be on your activity page.

Comment: @LadybugKiller Not a duplicate of that question at all.

Comment: I am in support of such a feature. Wish this question wasn't downvoted so much.

Answer (score 10):

Your browser already has this. I don't really see the need to have this as a site function.

Comment: Yes but what if I clear the history everyday, or I use a public computer. Its about maintaining your own private breadcrumb trail

Comment: -1 This will not work in a lot of situation!

Comment: I don't use the same computer everyday.

Comment: @Mallow many browsers can share favourites across the cloud (Chrome, Safari, FF with extensions IIRC). Maybe that'll work for you. You'll need favourites anyway - if you click through a lot of questions, a history feature will be worthless for you when searching for a specific question

Comment: @Pekka Usually I don't like the implementation of these things as it can download some private bookmarks on computers that I don't want them to appear on ever. A history of questions viewed would be helpful right now for me for a particular situation I am having. I can't find the answer this time. On the other hand, I can understand SO/SE not wanting to implement this as it would add loads of data that requires loads of storage.

Comment: @Pekka Additionally it doesn't matter how many favorites I can share in a cloud, if I just don't think I will need to save a page because I assume it will be an easy find. I still won't have that history as I did not act upon it.

Answer (score 4):

I like this idea. Generally speaking the tags are a good way of finding a question that you've seen before. However with popular tags like Java, C#, etc, questions can get buried rather quickly.

Having a history page organized chronologically can greatly ease looking for things and provide better organization to the site. I sometimes feel that the site moves too quickly for me with the constant flood of new questions. This feature would allow it to kind of slow down to my own pace.